# What is the difference between misc drivers and char drivers?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm reading about misc drivers in Linux, and I'm a little confused about the differences between them and char drivers. One source, [the Linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2920), writes:

> Alessandro tells us how to register a small device needing a single
>   entry point with the misc driver.
>   Sometimes people need to write
>   “small” device drivers, to support custom hacks—either hardware or
>   software ones. To this end, as well as to host some real drivers, the
>   Linux kernel exports an interface to allow modules to register their
>   own small drivers. The misc driver was designed for this purpose.

Ok, so from this I get that there's a simple driver (in this case with a single entry point), that's a misc driver. Then another source, Essential Linux Device Drivers, states:

> Misc (or miscellaneous) drivers are simple char drivers that share
>   certain common characteristics. Because misc drivers are char drivers,
>   the earlier discussion on char driver entry points hold for misc
>   drivers, too.

Now this seems to say that misc drivers **are** just char drivers, but perhaps a subset of functions, and char drivers can have more than one entry point (such as an `ioctl()` or an `open()` or a `read()` call)

So, what, in Linux C coding terms, are the differences between a char and misc device driver? (Besides the obvious major number assignment (10) for all misc drivers). Is there a difference in supported entry points? Is my assumption correct that misc device drivers only have a subset of what you can get in a full char device driver?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit**: I thought you were talking about `drivers/misc` drivers, but I see you're refering to character drivers using `misc_register` (and all the API in `drivers/char/misc.c`). You should specify this in your question.

In this case, the `misc` API seems to make your life easier when you're writing a small character driver and do not want to need to allocate a new major number only to use one minor number, for example. It simplifies things, but all the file operations are still available using the `fops` member of `struct miscdevice`. The basic difference is you only get one minor number per `misc` device.

My previous, **unrelated answer** was, for the record:

Have a quick look at [`drivers/misc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/misc): you won't find any "`misc` core" out there. This means: `misc` is not a device class; it's just a bunch of drivers that don't fit in any other category. Things like barometers, DACs, test suites and other strange things.

Look at the top of `drivers/misc/Kconfig`:

```
#
# Misc strange devices
#

menu "Misc devices"
```

*All* the items in this Kconfig do not depend on any "`misc` core", but on other cores (`i2c`, `pci`, `tty`, etc.). Usually, when a driver is really using a driver core, you will see it in its Kconfig. For instance, pretty much all `leds` drivers (`drivers/leds`) depend on the `leds` class core and have this in their [Kconfig node](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/Kconfig):

```
depends on LEDS_CLASS
```

Maybe `misc` drivers are all character drivers (I didn't check all of them), but something else would still *work* there, although it would probably be at the wrong place. I believe that lots of `misc` drivers could be moved to better places now... a veteran kernel hacker could confirm this.

So, to answer your question: `misc` drivers *do not have to be* character drivers, so the two categories are completely unrelated. A `misc` driver brings nothing more than a character driver because a `misc` driver is, again, nothing special.

**Update**: the [Honeywell compass driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/misc/hmc6352.c) is a great example. It is small and straightforward.

It communicates with the actual compass using I²C. This device won't show up as a character device, so forget about major number 10. It will, however, appear somewhere in Sysfs, under `/sys/bus/i2c/devices`, like all I²C devices do. And you will see the Sysfs attributes it adds to its group, like `heading0_input` that will show the current compass direction when read.

So here you have it: a `misc` driver that's not a character driver.

Comment: I added a small hint to the misc API to the original answer (has to be peer-reviewed). Do you mind to strip off the historical parts (the "Edit:" and the original answer) afterwards?

Answer (score 5):

> Now this seems to say that misc drivers are just char drivers, but perhaps a subset of functions, and char drivers can have more than one entry point (such as an ioctl() or an open() or a read() call)

Yes,it just Charater driver, and Misc driver also have multiple entry point read(), write(), ioctl() (because in miscdevice 's structure already have filefile_operations structure)

in my understanding, when we need to write  a small driver (only have one entry point or some more (2,3,... entry points) <<< mean small driver) we should use misc driver. it will prevent waste of RAM if we register new Major Number.

> Now  Since the kernel keeps a static table of device drivers, frivolous allocation of major numbers is rather wasteful of RAM. The Linux kernel, therefore, offers a simplified interface for simple drivers—those that will register a single entry point. Note that, in general, allocating the whole name space of a major number to every device is beneficial. This allows the handling of multiple terminals, multiple serial ports and several disk partitions without any overhead in the kernel proper: a single driver takes care of all of them, and uses the minor number to differentiate.